# Jest Error "Cannot read property 'validAttributes' of undefined" on ReactNative 0.48

Tags: react-native, jestjs

We have an app we recently updated from ReactNative 0.42 to 0.48.  In that update we migrated to Jest for testing (from mocha/chai/enzyme).  We are currently using Jest v21.1.0.  When I run each test manually, they all pass without error.  When I run just `yarn jest` I get this error:

```
/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2582
warnForStyleProps$1(nativeProps,viewConfig.validAttributes);
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'validAttributes' of undefined
    at setNativePropsStack$1 (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2582:43)
    at Component.setNativeProps (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeStack-dev.js:2550:1)
    at AnimatedProps.callback [as _callback] (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:1819:20)
    at AnimatedProps.update (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:1698:6)
    at /scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:230:69
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at _flush (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:230:16)
    at AnimatedValue._updateValue (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:939:1)
    at TimingAnimation.animation.start._this9._animation [as _onUpdate] (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:906:8)
    at TimingAnimation.onUpdate (/scratch/react_native_app/client/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:345:6)
```

I cannot be sure, but we only have two components that deal with Animations and timing.  We are using `jest.useFakeTimers();`  If I add a `jest.runAllTimers();` I can get the error on individual component.  The timing portions of the component look like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      Animated.timing(
        this.state.fadeAnim, {
          toValue: 1,
          delay: 2000
        }
      ).start();
  }
```

And

```
<Animated.View style={{ opacity: this.state.fadeAnim }}>
 ...
</Animated.View>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and even more puzzling: if run individually (each file), the tests are successful. When I run `npm run jest`, I've got this error.

Comment: @pietro909 I actually just figured this out late last week.  See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took quite some time, but I finally figured out what was going on.  Basically, more of my tests were rendering the Animated view then I thought.  I had originally included `jest.useFakeTimers();` in my specific test for the component, but then I moved that into a setup file named `test/jest_setup.js` and then added this to my `package.json` file:

```
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js",
      "./test/jest_setup.js"
    ],
    // rest of jest config
  }
```

Now my errors are gone!

Comment: The solution doesn't work. Btw, what's the difference between included jest.useFakeTimers(); and in test/jest_setup.js?